# change the default text Add Your Review to write review

Tags: review

As per requirement i need to change the default text "Add your review" to "write review". I want to know which file is containing that default text.

Comment: grep -rni 'Add Your Review'

Comment: @zhartaunik i didn't understand

Comment: I gave you an example how to find file with that error. app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/helper/summary.phtml here it is. You can copy this file to your theme and change directly there. @Marius variant is much better if you apply it

Comment: thanx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in the file `app/design/frontent/{package}/{theme}/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

```
"Add Your Review","Write review"
```

for other languages than `en_US` add the same line in `app/locale/{lang_CODE}/Mage_Review.csv`

Comment: /app/design/frontend/default/modern/locale/en_US its show same

Comment: is my path is correct?

Comment: if you are using the modern theme, then it's correct. If the file does not exist in your theme just create it.

Comment: /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml This the path which am using for product view. I am totally new to magento so please let me know where i create that file and folder because in rwd there is no such file named locale